# Starting with Git - individual commits and pushes? Or all at once?

Tags: git

We were just setup with a Git-TFS solution at my work. Up until now, important files were kept on network shares, in a format like so:

- Filex V1 20180101.zzz
- Filex V2 20181201.zzz
- Filex V3 20190101.zzz

Obviously I will rename the file to *Filex* before copying into the repository, starting with the oldest.
My question is, do I need to perform a Commit AND Push for each file-version I drop in my repository?  Or just Commit, and Git will see them as different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git commit` :  This command will commit the changes to your local repository.

`git push`: This command will push your local commits to the remote repository.

There is no need to do git push every time when the file content is changed , just do a git commit whenever you change the file and do a git push, after you are done with all your changes

For example.

1. Add a file to your repo folder.
2. git add and git commit.
3. Add a new version of the file
4. git add and git commit
5. Repeat step 3 and 4, till you reach the latest version.
6. Do a git push